# Не работает переход на новую страничку Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Пишу блог для себя, в рельсах еще учусь.
Проблема в том, что создаю на главной страничке кнопку для создания новой публикации, по нажатию на которую должна открываться страничка создания публикации. Но ничего не происходит.

В роутах

`resources :publications 
root "publications#index"`

Если сделать rake routes вывод такой

```
    `publications GET    /publications(.:format)          publications#index
                  POST   /publications(.:format)          publications#create
  new_publication GET    /publications/new(.:format)      publications#new
 edit_publication GET    /publications/:id/edit(.:format) publications#edit
      publication GET    /publications/:id(.:format)      publications#show
                  PATCH  /publications/:id(.:format)      publications#update
                  PUT    /publications/:id(.:format)      publications#update
                  DELETE /publications/:id(.:format)      publications#destroy
             root GET    /                                publications#index`
```

В application.html.erb
   `<%= link_to "New Post", new_publication_path%>`

Кнопка появляется, но при нажатии на нее ничего не происходит.

Comment: А что выводится в консоли сервера, при переходе по ссылке? Есть какие-то сообщения об ошибках?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался в своем вопросе. 
Оказывается не работало только в Firefox, в остальных браузерах все работало отлично.
Изменил строку в В application.html.erb `<%= link_to "New Post", new_publication_path%>`
На блок такого вида

`<%= link_to new_publication_path do %> 
   <button class="button">New Post</button> 
<% end %>`

И теперь работет во всех браузерах нормально

Comment: это вообще не то. `link_to` генерирует ссылку, тег `a`, то что здесь это семантически и вообще не верно. Сейчас код выглядит так `<a href=""><button>new post</button></a>`. так делать не нужно. Если перехода не было, проблема была в другом, возможно просто ошибка в html.